# .setClassToggle in ScrollMagic does not remove class when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

So i've been using ScrollMagic.js with GSAP.js and using the .setClassToggle for a side navigation active state as you scroll down.

It adds the 'active' class, but does not remove the previous one, until you scroll up again, then it removes it. But the demo shows it toggling both ways. This is my code:

```
$(function () {

  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#Home"})
              .setClassToggle(".side-nav a.home", "active")                
              .addTo(controller);
  new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#Overview"})
              .setClassToggle(".side-nav a.overview", "active")
              .addTo(controller);
});
```

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/2sx91ya6/

Comment: Can you provide fiddle with your code?

Comment: Sure thing: https://jsfiddle.net/2sx91ya6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Specify a duration (height of scene) property globally

  `var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {duration: 561}
  });`

  https://jsfiddle.net/2sx91ya6/4/
- or for each scene seperately.

  `new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: "#Home",
    duration: 561
  })`

  https://jsfiddle.net/trkaplan/2sx91ya6/5/

If scene heights are dynamic/or you don't want to specify manually, see the [example here](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/issues/500#issuecomment-216463444) to calculate duration for each scene.

Comment: Great! This definitely pointed me into the right direction. I just used the actual div's height for duration. duration: $('div-id').height()

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Specify that the element size to be 100%.

```
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {duration: "100%"}
});
```

I forked your original JS Fiddle so you can see this in action here:
https://jsfiddle.net/grayayer/1v6fusye/

this is described in the ScrollMagic documentation here: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/responsive_duration.html